# Alternative way to use not() pseudoclass in css

Tags: css, css-selectors

So lets say we have **N** children  and we want to use a selector to color them all expect the first child. Is there any possible way to do that without the use of :not(...) pseudo class?? The example is this:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
p:not(:first-child){
    background: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div><p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>



</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This selects and colors red all children expect the first but i want to do that **without the use of :not()** .Is there way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it the opposite way round?

```
<style> 
    p {background:#ff0000;}
    p:first-child {background:none;}
</style>
```

Comment: can you tell me a general way to access all children expect first without the use of not().Thanks for the answer already but if you could give me an extra tip would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxprsrky)

Use instead:

```
 p + p
```

Comment: it styles every element that is placed after the first p tag. Here is an example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp